# How get timezone offset from spring request?

Tags: java, spring, request, timezone, timezone-offset

I have class:

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api/user")
    public class UserCtrl {
      @RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
      public ResponseEntity updateUser(@RequestBody StringModel updateModel) {

    }
  }
```

How I can get Timezone offset with this request? It's possible?

It writes a date to update a user, but needs to save a time zone, or rather its offset, to correctly present the result.

Answer (score 2):

```
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    Locale locale = request.getLocale();
    Calendar calenda = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
    TimeZone timeZone = calenda.getTimeZone();
    int rawOffset = timeZone.getRawOffset();
    ZoneId zoneId = timeZone.toZoneId();
    ZoneRules rules = zoneId.getRules();
```

rawOffset have time in milliseconds, e.g 3600000 -> +01:00